# Incorrect number of CPU in android emulator

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

I’m using Visual Studio emulator for Android and I’m trying to emulate a single core device similar to google Nexus S however I end up with a 2 core device no matter what I do. In Hyper-V manager under settings I see 2 virtual processors. Same happens when I try to emulate a  4-core device and again I see 2 virtual processors in Hyper-V manager.  Benchmark tests show same values for those virtual devices.   Is this supposed to work like this?  How do I create a device with 1 or 4 core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the VS Emulator for Android only runs with two cores. No matter what values are "set" it, will revert to 2 cores. If that's a feature you'd like to see, feel free to let us know on our UserVoice page: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/category/91622-vs-emulator-for-android

Answer (score 0):

you can setup a Nexus S emulator right from within Visual Studio.

I was able to go to Tools -> Android -> Android Emulator Manager

[image]

From there I clicked on Create

[image]

And then I chose Nexus S and setup all required settings.

[image]

Do you have the same options and does this setup the emulator you are looking for?

Comment: I use [Microsoft emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx)

Comment: Steps you give are for AVD, which is not the product this question is about.